# MongoDB:How to set a MAX limit on an Int64 field in a document?

Tags: mongodb

I am implementing a feature that sets a disk space quota for each user so that the total size of a user's uploaded resources does not exceed a certain limit. I am storing the disk space usage information in the 'currentUsage' field of the user document.

I want to set a max limit on the 'currentUsage' field, if the limit is exceeded during an update, it throws an exception which I catch and show the message to the user. Can it be done easily with Mongodb?

Thanks

Comment: Normally this is something done using business logic in the application

Comment: because of the non transactional nature of Mongodb, i will need to do some munual locking in the aplication code or create a counter to ensure correctness. if mongodb supports the max limit feature out of box, then I won't need to do the extra work.

Comment: You could just do it in the find query, i.e. `update({user_id:id, currentUsage:{$lt:user.allowUsage}}, {$set: {//blah blah}})` whereby `user` would be the object you received earlier, that way it is transactional.

Comment: Thanks for that, however, that query finds the user whose currentUsage is less than allowUsage before the update then updates it. It will allow setting the currentUsage to any value.

Comment: This question reminds me about [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-number-js). It's done in the application layer.